# Scale out a Gluster Disperse Volume

Tags: glusterfs

I've been playing with Gluster for a few hours to see if it will fit our needs and so far so good. However, I've been looking around the internet for the "how to" of expanding a dispersed volume and have come up empty. I can easily find it for distributed or striped volumes but never dispersed.

My lab consist of 5 servers with a single ZFS brick per server.

I started with only 3 servers configured as "disperse-data 2 redundancy 1" and all went well.

What I want to do is scale out from there, add another redundancy and doing "disperse-data 2 redundancy 2" then another and do "disperse-data 3 redundancy 2".

So far, adding a single brick yields an error as follow "volume add-brick: failed: Incorrect number of bricks supplied 1 with count 3".

Thanks